# VIM for windows doesn't load vimrc file from current directory

Tags: vim

i starting to use VIM for windows, i download the minimal windows vim exe from here:
http://www.vim.org/download.php#pc
i created simple vimrc file that is located in the gvim.exe directory that looks like this :
vimrc:

```
set secure exrc
"disable beep 
set noeb vb t_vb=

"color scheme
set background=dark
highlight Normal guibg=Black guifg=White

"remove topbar
set guioptions-=T
```

the thing is that when i execute the gvim.exe , it doesn't load the vimrc
it load it only when from within vim i run :

```
:e vimrc
:so %
```

what i missing here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your plugins, colorschemes, etc. are supposed to be here:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles
```

Your vimrc is supposed to be there:

```
%userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc
```

Comment: I'm sure I've answered that very same question a dozen of times already.

Comment: well my main question is can't it be in the VIM installation directory ?
not in $HOME / %userprofile%

Comment: The installation directory is off limits for you.

Comment: ok thanks , so the installation dir is for plugins ( that i tried and it works )

Comment: No, the installation directory is for Vim, not for you. Put everything in `%userprofile%\vimfiles`, without any exception.

Comment: What's not being said here is that you *should not* put config in the install directory, because (1) it will get trashed every time you install a new version, (2) it applies to *all* users on the machine, who may not agree with your personal settings, and (3) it requires admin rights to access. But Vim does look there (in the parent directory). It just looks for a "_vimrc" file, not a "vimrc" file. And only, if it did not already find one in $HOME/vimfiles.

Comment: I've put the _vimrc file to %userprofile%\vimfiles, then to %userprofile%\vimfiles\vimrc and both options didn't work... doesn't matter if I named the file _vimrc or vimrc.